# Web Map and Web Map Classic Arcade

Tags: esri

I am not sure if this is the correct Community ''folder'' where to post this, but I have a question relating to the wonderful workflow as demonstrated in this video Inspection Workflows Part 2: [Web Map Creation & Dynamic Symbology](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqC-EEw3nxY&t=0s)

Two questions:

1. Is it possible to Access the water utilities Symbology also on the new Map Viewer? I see it neatly in the Classic..
2. Is it just me or when using the same method of IIF+DateDiff as to define symbology for points that have been inspected recently and those that have to be inspected - it works only in the Map Viewer Classic? Is it because the Layer View is added to the map? I tried a workaround - created layer view by Join Analysis and added it to the Map Viewer Map. Used the same Arcade that is in the demonstration. Worked great for the Map Viewer Classic Map. Ignores the second part of the expression in Map Viewer.

I would be happy if anyone could give a comment if this is how it's supposed to be for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glad we're making progress on the first point! But I think I know the error for the second point, it's a tricky one!

According to your Arcade expression, you have two values, right?

- "Inspected more than a year ago"
- "Recent inspection"

Even though you put these two values correctly into the arcade expression, the map still doesn't technically know that these two values exist... until inpsection records are submitted that meet each of the provided criteria (inspection within the last year OR inspection not in the last year).

So, if you built the arcade epxression and all of your inspections are within the last year, you can symbolize everything by "Recent inspection" because the map has data that supports this first part fo the expression. Until you add an inspection record that occured "more than a year ago", the map won't register this value in the symbology and it will ignore that second part fo the arcade expression. However, once you add an inspection record that meets the second criteria, you'll still have to go into the symbology and manually turn on the "Inspected more than a year ago" symbology. But it will work since a record meeting this criteria is available for the arcade expression to consume.

I ran through the symbology workflow and when I had no inspection records submitted, I couldn't use either of your two values. I got a generic "Other" value. I added an inspection record with today's date and was able to add the "Recent inspection" value. Then, I added an inspection record and falsified the date to be three years ago; this allowed me to add the "Inspected more than a year ago" symbology color.

Here's my suggestion: when using an arcade expression like this to drive symbology, create "fake" inspections records that will trick the map to thinking that all of your different criteria are met. This way you can apply your: "Inspected more than a year ago" and "Recent inspection" symbologies.

Finally, it makes sense that the symbology from the Map Viewer Classic pulled into the New Map Viewer. Just like the utility symbology, the New Map Viewer will pull on that Map Viewer Classic's symbology.